# What is the exact word for vintage fashion which is returning in present time?

Tags: word-request

My native language is not English. I want to know the word about fashion (past) which is returned in present. Remake is not the right word but I think something like this.

Comment: _Vintage_ is as exact as it gets. Unless you want to specify the year.

Comment: You may be thinking of [retro](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retro).

Comment: I think it might be "revolution". For example - this dress is revolution from past fashion.

Comment: Never heard it called revolution, which means new. Retro, vintage, or ___ revival.

Comment: A "fashion revolution" would be a significant change in fashion with something new replacing more established things (same sense as a political revolution). I agree with Stuart's suggestion: "revival".

Comment: Also _come full circle_.

Answer (score 2):

> **make a comeback**
>
> *Colloquial* (originally U.S.). A return to a former state of success, popularity, viability, etc.; spec. a return by a well-known person to
> a former position of authority or success. OED online

> **comeback** (n.)
>
> A return to popularity: *Wide ties are **making a comeback** this year.*
> [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=comeback)

---

> Fashion trends used to take 30 years to come back into style; now they
> **make a comeback** in 10 or 20. [Ann Anderson; *High School Prom*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/High_School_Prom/WCLjW3bh9QUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=dresses%20once%20popular%20in%20the%20%20are%20making%20a%20comeback&pg=PA81&printsec=frontcover) (2012)

> Three-Quarter. Ending midway between the elbow and the wrist, this
> sleeve style has **made a big comeback** in the fashion world. [Carley
> Roney; *The Knot Book of Wedding Gowns*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Knot_Book_of_Wedding_Gowns/Ca3-PPUXV6MC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=dresses%20once%20popular%20in%20the%20%20are%20making%20a%20comeback&pg=PA59&printsec=frontcover) (2001)